# Why Using Compound Statement Here?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Below is a snippet from [FBKVOController](https://github.com/facebook/kvocontroller).

```
  _FBKVOInfo *info;

  {
    // lookup context in registered infos, taking out a strong reference
    // only if it exists
    OSSpinLockLock(&_lock);
    info = [_infos member:(__bridge id)context];
    OSSpinLockUnlock(&_lock);
  }

  if (nil != info) {
```

What is the compound statement {...} here for?

Comment: I would guess it's there strictly for code readability; you can better see where the spin lock is applied. There is no functional reason for it to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I group statements into blocks, too, to simply show a strong linkage. Likely the programmer did it to show the scope of the lock.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage to using a compound statement there, as far as I can see.

If it was C++ and the lock object was defined within the block and used RAII semantics (where is was automatically unlocked on destruction), it would make sense.  However as it stands, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Compound statement is a sequence of statements surrounded by braces, in this construct, parentheses go around the braces.
As i can see, in your example parentheses is only for code readability.